# How does overriding variables actually work?

Tags: c

My teacher gave me some code and asked me what is printed but it includes overriding variables on some cases while on others it doesnt and it gets really confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int w, x, y, z = 10;

void f(int y){
    w += 5;
    x += 6;
    y += 7;
}

int main(void) {
    int w;
    w = x = y = z = 1;

    f(z);

    printf ("%d %d %d %d\n", w, x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that the `f(z)` function would go to the `void f` and increment `w` by 5, `x` by 6, `y` by 7 and `z` would stay 1 since all global variables are overwritten in the main function.

It turns out though that the result is 1 7 1 1

Comment: Please format your code properly. Readability is very important.

Comment: @Bodo, thanks for taking the time to make the edit. But do make sure you leave the code compilable.

Comment: BTW: it's not _overriding_ but _shadowing_.

Comment: @Bathsheba The bug was already present in the original code. When editing for readability I don't see it as my responsibility to try and compile the code.

Comment: [Here is some background](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) on the scope of variables.

Answer (score 5):

The `w` at global scope is initialised automatically to 0.

The *automatic* variables in `main` *shadow* the global ones *only* in `main`.

The parameter `y` in `f` *shadows* the global `y`.

(Note my careful use of terminology here; *shadowing* is the correct term - *overriding* is used to describe the substitution of one function for another in polymorphic programming.)

Comment: If the parameter y in f shadows the global y then why doesn't it shadow x as well? Or if it shadows y then why doesn't y take the value of 7+1 = 8? I may not make much sense because i am new in programming and i don't know the terminology and the processes really well.

Comment: @OrfeasChasaneas: There's already a comprehensive answer to this (Vlad). Which part of that answer is not clear?

Comment: So let me tell you what i have understood.
Because w is declared in main no matter what it will get the value that is assigned to it unaffected by the function f
Then, x, will at first take the value 0 and then the value that is assigned to it in main which is 1. The f function will be applied to it so it will become 7.
y is a little confusing to me since it is in function f so it should go from 1 to 1+7=8 and then printed. Or is it taking the value of z because f(z)?
Finally z as it doesn't exist in the function f will just take the value assigned to it in main which is 1 and then printed

Answer (score 3):

In main there is declared only one local variable `w`.

The global variables `x, y, z` are reinitialized in this statement

```
w = x = y = z = 1;
```

that is they are set to 1.

Within the function

```
void f(int y){
w += 5;
x += 6;
y + = 7;
}
```

there are used all global variables including `w` and `x` and the parameter (local variable of the function) y.

So w is set to 5, x is set to 7 ( 1 + 6 ) and the parameter y is set to 8 ( 1 + 7 ).

Changing the parameter does not influence on the value of the global variable y.

In this call in main

```
printf ("%d %d %d %d\n", w, x, y, z);
```

there is used the local variable w that was early set to 1.

SO the output will be

```
1 7 1 1
```

Comment: @OrfeasChasaneas The variable declared in an inner scope hides a variable with the same name in an outer scope. So you are right. w declared in main hides the global variable w in the block scope of main.

Comment: Nice and thorough, as usual ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For W : since you defined a local variable int w the actions outside main doesn't affect its value

For X : the variable is global and value is modified in main (1) then f(+6 => 7)

For Y : since you defined a parameter named y in f() the global variable with the same name won't be used

For Z : since your parameter is a int (and not a pointer) the modification on the parameter won't be kept once the treatment leaves f() (the parameter act as a copy z).

The behavior is clearer if you write it like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int global_w, global_x, global_y, global_z = 10;

void f(int param_y) {
    global_w += 5;
    global_x += 6;
    param_y += 7;
}

int main(void) {
    int local_w;

    local_w = global_x = global_y = global_z = 1;
    f(global_z);
    printf ("%d %d %d %d\n", local_w, global_x, global_y, global_z);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting that the `f(z)` function would go to the would go to the `f` and increment increment `w` by 5, `x` by 6, `y` by 7 and `z` would stay 1 since all global variables are overwritten in the `main` function.

Yes, this is *exactly* what is happening. You just need to find out *what is `w` and `y`*.

This is not called **overriding** but **shadowing**. You can make it visible with e.g. using GCC with `-Wshadow` argument ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/NNMj8a)):

```
<source>: In function 'f':

<source>:4:12: warning: declaration of 'y' shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]

    4 | void f(int y){
      |        ~~~~^

<source>:2:11: note: shadowed declaration is here

    2 | int w, x, y, z = 10;
      |           ^

<source>: In function 'main':

<source>:11:9: warning: declaration of 'w' shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]

   11 |     int w;
      |         ^

<source>:2:5: note: shadowed declaration is here

    2 | int w, x, y, z = 10;
      |     ^

Compiler returned: 0
```

The shadowing variable is present *only* in the scope where it is declared and after its declaration within that *scope* you can use that name refer to only that object, not the shadowed one.